# cannot understand the finish method android

Tags: java, android

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  //if user is already logged in open the profile activity directly
  if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, Home.class));
  }
  buttonSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
  buttonSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Can someone please explain to me why is `finish()` called before launching the `Home.class` if the user is already logged in. I'm trying to go through some source code and not able to understand this.

Comment: Program execution does not stop after you call finish(). It just means "finish this activity, and then start the Home activity".

Comment: Okay, so does finish looks for startActivty() function?

Comment: What if i have some line of codes in between finish and startActivity?

Comment: found what i exactly needed after https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18111245/is-it-a-good-idea-to-call-finish-after-starting-a-new-activity-in-android Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

After `finish()` you can't get context from the activity.

You have to start activity like this:

```
if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {            
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Home.class));
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: So is it a better idea to call finish after starting a newactivty?

Comment: yes, its right way

Answer (score 0):

simply when you call finish();
its more like an intent which do this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(whereYouareActivity.this , mainActivity.class};
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you finish an activity, the activity gets destroyed but not the process. This is an important aspect of Android programming and is important to understand how it's different from other platforms.

And you can finish your activity by adding these lines :-

```
if (SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()) {            
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Home.class));
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling `finish()` you actively close your current Activity. This prevents your activity from being shown again when the user presses the back button.